# Is there a way to add the setuid bit to a mac application bundle?

Tags: macos, posix, setuid, .app

I want to make a separate version of TextEdit owned by root with setuid so I didn't always have to use `nano` and other terminal-based text editors to edit config files and the like. Is there an easier way to do this other than just invoking their internal binary from terminal using `su`?

Comment: Use [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) instead. It can request admin credentials when needed to edit system files, won't trip you up by trying to use formatting, "smart" quotes, add unexpected file extensions, etc. It's also free. Just be sure to get the download version from barebones.com, not the App Store version, since the App Store version had some of the really cool features ripped out to comply with Apple's security rules. (There's also TextWrangler's big brother, [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/), but it's not free.)

Comment: Oh, thanks! I had TextWrangler, but I didn't know it had that feature.